# Is it possible to decide which columns can be unchecked by columntoggler primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

As i wrote on the question, is it possible to decide which column shown by columnToggler? I need to let the user check and uncheck some columns but set as disabled others.

Comment: This is a 'Read the fine manual' question: https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PrimeFaces documentation on page 107](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#107) states the following:

```
Name          Default   Type         Description
toggleable    true      Boolean      Defines if panel is toggleable by columnToggler component. Default value is true and a false value marks
```

the column as static.

So using something like

```
<p:column toggleable="false" ...>
    ...
</p:column
```

Would fit your requirement. See also page and [173](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#173) (emphasis mine)

> On page load, column chooser finds all columns of datatable and generates the ui. If you'd like some of the columns to be ignored, **set toggleable
>    option of a column as false** and for certain ones to be hidden by default,  set visible
>    as false.